# When editing feature-linked annotation with font color white, the annotation disappears

Tags: annotation

When moving or editing the annotation, the annotation disappears. We are editing on a black background, so the text isn't just blending in to the background. The attribute table does not show any abnormality, but the "Zoom to Selected" option is grayed out. It can be selected in the table, but does not display in the display window. Anyone have this problem? Found any solutions?

Comment: Alyssa D merged your duplicate account http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/2735/lyzi

Comment: I have a similar problem with editing points. When I move the point it just disappears. Still shows up in the attr table but gone from the map. An undo and re-try will often remedy the problem. I will try to get esri to duplicate as bug when I get a round tuit.

Comment: Alyssa, which software (and version) are you using? ArcGIS 10.0?

Comment: Yes, we are working in 10.

Comment: @ Brad -- I had a similar problem today at work. I just installed the latest patch for ArcView 10 too. Is this the case at your end? - meaning did you just install the latest patch? I tried a few things, and I ultimately had to redo the symbology and add the point again for it to show up. It was very odd!!  All I did is move the point slightly and it was gone.  It was in the attribute table, I could select it, but I could not get it to show up without removing it then adding it again in the symbology options.

Comment: @ Dano - I had the problem on sp1 (not the latest). But have just had sp2 (the latest) installed for two or three days. Haven't done that function since installing. It looks like it is reproducable [ESRI] @Alyssa D - I would be interested to see if your problem occurs even if you make the symbol black or other color?

Comment: @Brad We're using one Annotation FC with lots of different annotation classes. This is only occuring with the group of annotation classes that are symbolized white -- the ones that were symbolized 60K, 80K and 90K were doing fine.

Comment: hmm - it sounded like the same problem I am having until you said that. - ???

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anybody else runs into this problem and lands on this page.  Try:

-- Repair geometry
-- Rebuild the spatial index (use the Add Spatial Index tool)

The latter worked for me when features in an Annotation Class were disappear upon zooming in.

Good luck,

AZ